# MySQL delete statement with subquery in IN cluase and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I tried to delete records which condition related to another table and I also want to limit records that will be deleted.

```
DELETE e.* FROM employees e
WHERE emp_no IN (
    SELECT ee.emp_no
    FROM (
        SELECT e.emp_no
        FROM employees e, salaries s
        WHERE e.emp_no = s.emp_no
        GROUP BY e.emp_no
        HAVING COUNT(s.emp_no) = 1)
    ee) 
AND emp_no NOT IN (
    SELECT dmm.emp_no
    FROM (
        SELECT dm.emp_no
        FROM dept_manager dm)
    dmm)
LIMIT 8384
```

but I get an error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 8384' at line 17

I wonder is this because its condition, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You do not need the _.*_ on  _e.*_  (you are deleting the rows, not the values in the columns on rows). But that isn't the main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting from a single table, which for some reason MySQL doesn't support table alias' for:-

```
DELETE 
FROM employees 
WHERE emp_no IN (
    SELECT ee.emp_no
    FROM (
        SELECT e.emp_no
        FROM employees e, salaries s
        WHERE e.emp_no = s.emp_no
        GROUP BY e.emp_no
        HAVING COUNT(s.emp_no) = 1)
    ee) 
AND emp_no NOT IN (
    SELECT dmm.emp_no
    FROM (
        SELECT dm.emp_no
        FROM dept_manager dm)
    dmm)
LIMIT 8384
```

Comment: Thanks, it really weird.

Answer (score 0):

For what i see  you can avoid  e.* and you missed the alias e.emp

```
DELETE  FROM employees e
WHERE e.emp_no IN (
    SELECT ee.emp_no
    FROM (
        SELECT e.emp_no
        FROM employees e, salaries s
        WHERE e.emp_no = s.emp_no
        GROUP BY e.emp_no
        HAVING COUNT(s.emp_no) = 1)
    ee  ) 
AND e.emp_no NOT IN (
    SELECT dmm.emp_no
    FROM (
        SELECT dm.emp_no
        FROM dept_manager dm)
    dmm )
LIMIT 8384
```